# Cancel onbeforeunload popup

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Did the behavior change in Chrome 51, where now not only that you cannot specify a custom message for the unload popup, but you cannot cancel the event at all?

It used to be possible to assign an empty function or null to the window.onbeforeunload, but that doesn't seem to work anymore in Chrome 51.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Custom message has been removed, but the event itself is there:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Comment: I know that the event is still there, my question was how do you cancel it once you set it? It used to be possible to assign it again to an empty function or null, but that doesn't seem to work anymore in Chrome 51.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function () { }` works fine for me in v.51. Please show the code, maybe we'll find the issue there